# Does your Twilio SMS balance ever expire?

Tags: twilio

I tried looking for a solution in their documentation, but I couldn't find anything. Perhaps I might've been searching the wrong way.

Anyway, if I would add $100 to my SMS balance, and I never send a text message (or at least less than $100), will that (remaining) balance ever *expire*?

Specific example: if I want to send 1 message per week, can I just put €50 on my SMS balance and use it for *eternity*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SMS, pricing is [usage-based](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/pricing), or pay-as-you-go. However, you should think about monthly recurring costs (MRC) such as phone numbers. For instance, when you buy a phone number, keeping it will result in monthly payments.

For more info, check out [How Twilio Billing Works](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223135487-How-Twilio-billing-works).